# How to pause a Runnable() Object for testing purposes

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency, sleep

I have the following situation:
I'm submitting n threads to a NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor in this way:

```
while ( index < customers.length ) {
    threadPoolExecutor.submit( new Runnable() {                       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            //callToExternalServiceHere;
            response = mockWebService();
        }
    });
    index++;
}
```

Every thread calls an external webservice, which is still not available to us. So i ended up creating a mock class that returns a response with some data in it. Now I'd like to be able to simulate a delay in the response, how can i accomplish this goal?

Thanks in advance

Update:

This is the code i use to instantiate the NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor

```
public static NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor getThreadPoolExecutor() {
    if ( instance.threadPoolExecutor == null ) {
        int numThread = 0;
        int availableProcessors = Runtime.getRuntime().availableProcessors();
        System.out.println( "CheckMultiTransaction - getThreadPoolExecutor - availableProcessors: " + availableProcessors );
        if ( WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_NUMTHREAD ) != null ) {
            numThread = Integer.parseInt( WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_NUMTHREAD ) );
            System.out.println( "CheckMultiTransaction - getThreadPoolExecutor - numThread indicati nella S_SYSTEM: " + numThread );
            numThread = numThread > availableProcessors ? availableProcessors : numThread;
        }
        else {
            numThread = availableProcessors;
        }

        System.out.println( "CheckMultiTransaction - getThreadPoolExecutor - numThread : " + numThread );
        int queueSize = numThread * 2; // recommended - twice the size of the poolSize
        int threadKeepAliveTime = 15;
        TimeUnit threadKeepAliveTimeUnit = TimeUnit.SECONDS;

        long maxBlockingTime = 10;
        TimeUnit maxBlockingTimeUnit = TimeUnit.MILLISECONDS;
        boolean useTimeoutQueue = false;
        if ( WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_MAXBLOCKINGTIME ) != null ) {
            maxBlockingTime = Long.parseLong( WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_MAXBLOCKINGTIME ) );
            useTimeoutQueue = true;
        }
        final boolean useTimeoutQueueThread = useTimeoutQueue;
        System.out.println( "THREAD_MULTITRN_MAXBLOCKINGTIME:" + WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_MAXBLOCKINGTIME ) );

        Callable<Boolean> blockingTimeoutCallback = new Callable<Boolean>() {
            @Override
            public Boolean call() throws Exception {
                System.out.println( "blockingTimeoutCallback - useTimeoutQueue:" + useTimeoutQueueThread + " - Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted():" + Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted() );
                if ( useTimeoutQueueThread )
                    return false;
                else
                    return !Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted(); // keep waiting
            }
        };

        instance.threadPoolExecutor = new NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor( numThread, queueSize, threadKeepAliveTime, threadKeepAliveTimeUnit, maxBlockingTime, maxBlockingTimeUnit, blockingTimeoutCallback );
    }
    return instance.threadPoolExecutor;
}
```

Comment: You should add some logic and sleep/delay in mockWebService() method

Comment: i thought about that, but the weird thing is that if i put say a Thread.sleep(10000) inside the mockWebService(), every other thread is CREATED 10 seconds after the last. It looks like i'm putting to sleep the main thread, not the runnable

Comment: what do you mean by "every other thread is CREATED 10 seconds after the last"

Comment: Let's say that i want to run 5 threads. By adding a Thread.sleep(10000) inside the mockWebService(), i can see from the logs that every thread is created 10 seconds after the last. So, for example, the first thread is created at 18:02:27, the second one is created at 18:02:37, the third one at 18:02:47, and so on. It looks like i'm putting to sleep the main thread, the one who is looping and calling submit, while i need to put the runnable to sleep. I believe i'm missing something...

Comment: @rekotc Can you reveal the code that creates `threadPoolExecutor` executor service?

Comment: @yauheni added the details in my question, thanks for your help

Answer (score 1):

You definitely can call `Thread.sleep(5000)` in `mockWebService()` method to make 5 seconds delay. Or just put `Thread.sleep(5000)` into `Runnable` e.g.

```
threadPoolExecutor.submit( new Runnable() {                       
        @Override
        public void run() {
            Thread.sleep(5000);
            //callToExternalServiceHere;
            response = mockWebService();
        }
    });
```

But, I would rather recommend you to use some library for mock testing, e.g.Mockito, to create mock of web service object. In this case you will be able to manage behavior of your mock web service in more flexible way. For example, to force mock web service to do some delay you would do something like:

```
Mockito.doAnswer(new Answer() {
   public Object answer(InvocationOnMock invocation) {
       Thread.sleep(<delay_timeout>);
       return "web_service_response_body_object";
   }})
 .when(webServiceMock).doWebServiceCall();
```

Refer to Mockito [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html) and to `Mockito.doAnswer` method [documentation](https://static.javadoc.io/org.mockito/mockito-core/3.0.0/org/mockito/Mockito.html#doAnswer-org.mockito.stubbing.Answer-) for more details.

Answer (score 0):

Problem solved. The thread.sleep() didn't work as expected because the numThread was equal to 1 in the configuration:

```
numThread = Integer.parseInt( WSConfiguration.getProperty( WSConstants.THREAD_MULTITRN_NUMTHREAD ) );
```

So the threadPoolExecutor (created using numThread as the parameter for poolSize) was limited to just one thread at a time, it wasn't running in parallel at all.

```
instance.threadPoolExecutor = new NotifyingBlockingThreadPoolExecutor( numThread, queueSize, threadKeepAliveTime, threadKeepAliveTimeUnit, maxBlockingTime, maxBlockingTimeUnit, blockingTimeoutCallback );
```

Thanks everybody for your help.